# Remove Ugly Sharp Corners when a Window is Maximized - GNOME

Tags: gnome, window, maximized

Is there a way to keep the window **titlebar corners rounded** when **maximized**? As a former MacOS user, I find it ugly when I maximize a window and it's sharp like that, especially since the dock is right next to the window. I want to keep the window rounded.

Here's my example:

[image]

Info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- GNOME
- Yes, all windows do this

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Possibly by tweaking `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file.

Comment: @FedKad there is only one line in this file that says `@import 'colors.css';`

Comment: This is particularly important when the dock is set to not fill all vertical space and is set to not auto-hide. In that case, maximized windows do not look maximized because they sit next to the dock.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? @AlexFullinator

Comment: @nrion No, I didn't find a solution yet.